# Lock sprite center to tile centers of tilemap

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to be able to drag a sprite across a tilemap but am having trouble making the sprite lock to the tiles. First I had:

```
- (void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

objectInTouch.position=touchlocation;

}
```

That didn't work because it uses the screen coordinates instead of the tilemap's? 
Then I figured that each tile is 16x16 px so I would make a "border" around the sprite (objectInTouch) and depending on if it hit the top, bottom, left, or right, the sprite would move accordingly. Here's what I tried but I get "Expression is not assignable."

```
- (void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

int xborder = objectInTouch.position.x+16;
int yborder = objectInTouch.position.y+16;
int xleftborder = objectInTouch.position.x-16;
int ybottomborder = objectInTouch.position.y-16;


if(touchLocation.x >= xborder)
    objectInTouch.position.x = objectInTouch.position.x+16;   -> Expression not assignable
if(touchLocation.y >= yborder)
    objectInTouch.position.y = objectInTouch.position.y+16;   -> Expression not assignable
if(touchLocation.x <= xleftborder)
    objectInTouch.position.x = objectInTouch.position.x-6;;   -> Expression not assignable
if(touchLocation.y <= ybottomborder)
    objectInTouch.position.y = objectInTouch.position.y-16;   -> Expression not assignable


}
```

Oh and if anyone could refer me to some good books/documents on this sort of stuff that'd be great!

Thanks!

Comment: oIt.position = ccpAdd(oIt.position,ccp(16,0)); for your xborder, and so on

Comment: So simple yet so perfect. What's your address so I can send you a cake or something? I've just been trying to resolve this for a while and you just did it! :)